# Vue JS $refs not adding a class to an elements classList when mounted

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using Vue JS with Laravel and Material Design Lite.

If my form fails a validator on the backend, when I redirect I pass the component a prop named `old`, which contains the previously selected options.

I've noticed that if I try to add the `is-checked` class to the labels when a component is mounted, it does not appear. E.g.

Template Code

```
...
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect pa" :ref="`option${option.id}`">
...
```

Script Code

```
...
mounted(): {
    if(this.old){
        this.selectedOptions = JSON.parse(this.old);
        for(let id of this.selectedOptions){
            this.$refs[`option${id}`][0].classList.add('is-checked');
        }
    }
}
...
```

What I find odd is that when I wrap the above script code in a `setTimeout(()=>{...}, 1000)` function it all of a sudden works. Also, the below code also logs the correct elements too:

```
...
mounted(): {
    if(this.old){
        this.selectedOptions = JSON.parse(this.old);
        for(let id of this.selectedOptions){
            console.log(this.$refs[`option${id}`][0].classList);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: uses `vm.$nextTick` to wrap the codes which will operate the Dom.

Comment: @Sphinx I've tried wrapping the inside of the mounted function as such `this.$nextTick(() => { ... });` but I had no success.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding a class to the DOM elements manually like that anyway, use `v-bind` instead.

Comment: @DecadeMoon that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.